# Get dynamic group of checkboxes grouped by an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

im developing an ACL manager and permissions on ACL GUI are created dynamically based on controllers in database. So if they are 3 controllers for example, I get 3 groups of 4 checkboxes (read, write, delete, execute). They have different ids, value based on checkbox (read=r, write=w...) and same data-id as controller id.

[image]

```
<ul class="list-group">
home                    
<li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_read1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="1">
        <label for="check_permisssion_read1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_write1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="1">
        <label for="check_permisssion_write1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_delete1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="1">
        <label for="check_permisssion_delete1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_execute1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="1">
        <label for="check_permisssion_execute1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
acl                    
<li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_read2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="2">
        <label for="check_permisssion_read2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_write2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="2">
        <label for="check_permisssion_write2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_delete2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="2">
        <label for="check_permisssion_delete2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_execute2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="2">
        <label for="check_permisssion_execute2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
acl_funcion1                    
<li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_read3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="3">
        <label for="check_permisssion_read3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_write3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="3">
        <label for="check_permisssion_write3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_delete3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="3">
        <label for="check_permisssion_delete3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="check_permisssion_execute3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="3">
        <label for="check_permisssion_execute3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
</li>
```

So when I click on save button, I need to get checked checkboxes but grouped by data-id, how can I get this?

I only got looping all checkboxes and checking if is checked, if is, return data-id+value (1r, 1w...) for example.

```
var checkboxes = $('.acl_permission');
        checkboxes.each(function(idx, el){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                console.log($(this).data('id') + $(this).val())
            }
        });
```

But like this, im getting:

```
1r
1w
2r
2w
3w
```

I would like to get something like:

`[{data-id: 1, permissions: 'rw'}, {data-id: 2, permissions: 'rw'}, {data-id: 3, permissions: 'w'}]` based on data-id (controller id) and permissions checked on that data-id (r,w,d,e).

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please include the HTML in your question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sure, there you have!

Comment: Is there a separate `<ul>` in each group? The html shown is invalid....can't put text directly inside a `<ul>`

Comment: @charlietfl that html is what I get on live, after process php data... <ul> is for all checkboxes.

Comment: Well note that it isn't valid

Comment: Yeah thanks, i wrapped into a `<li>` @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps:

- Add data-group attribute to your checkboxes
- Create a dictionary var permissions = { groupId: permissionString }
- On your loop : if permissions contains key with groupId add permission key to permissionString else add new groupId with permissionString

  ```
  var checkboxes = $('.acl_permission');
  var permissionDictionary = {};
  checkboxes.each(function(idx, el){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

          var groupId = $(this).attr('data-id')

          if !permissionDictionary[groupId] { 
              permissionDictionary[groupId] = "" 
          } 

          permissionDictionary[groupId] = permissionDictionary[groupId] + $(this).val() 
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Working like a charm! Very simple and effective, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary object whose keys are the data_id and values are the permissions. Then Use `Object.keys()` to `map()` final results from that object

```js
var  tmp ={};
$('.acl_permission:checked').each(function(){
   var data_id = $(this).data('id');   
   if(!tmp[data_id]) {
      tmp[data_id] =''
   }
   tmp[data_id]+= this.value
});

var res = Object.keys(tmp).map((key)=> ({data_id: key, permissions: tmp[key]}));

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  home
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_read1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="1"  checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_read1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_write1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="1" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_write1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_delete1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="1">
      <label for="check_permisssion_delete1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_execute1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="1" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_execute1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  acl
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_read2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="2">
      <label for="check_permisssion_read2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_write2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="2" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_write2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_delete2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="2">
      <label for="check_permisssion_delete2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_execute2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="2" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_execute2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  acl_funcion1
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_read3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="3">
      <label for="check_permisssion_read3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_write3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="3" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_write3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_delete3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="3" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_delete3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_execute3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="3">
      <label for="check_permisssion_execute3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .push the object with inside the each function .And add the `data_id` instead of `data-id` .

if you need to update the array with each time click .try with `onchange` event like this

```
$('.acl_permission').click(function(){
    var res = [];
    var checkboxes = $('.acl_permission');
    checkboxes.each(function(idx, el) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var some = res.map(a => a.data_id)
        if (some.includes($(this).data('id'))) {
          res.forEach(a =>
           { if (a.data_id == $(this).data('id')) {
              a.permissions = a.permissions + $(this).val()
            }})
        } else {
          res.push({
            data_id: $(this).data('id'),
            permissions: $(this).val()
          })
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(res)
})
```

**Updated**

```js
var res = [];
var checkboxes = $('.acl_permission');
checkboxes.each(function(idx, el) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var some = res.map(a => a.data_id) //validate the data_id exist
    if (some.includes($(this).data('id'))) {
      res.forEach(a =>
       { if (a.data_id == $(this).data('id')) {  
          a.permissions = a.permissions + $(this).val()//append to permission on exsit data_id permissions
        }})
    } else {
      res.push({  //its new data_id push with array
        data_id: $(this).data('id'),
        permissions: $(this).val()
      })
    }
  }
});
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  home
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_read1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="1" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_read1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_write1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="1">
      <label for="check_permisssion_write1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_delete1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="1" checked>
      <label for="check_permisssion_delete1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_execute1" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="1">
      <label for="check_permisssion_execute1" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  acl
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_read2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="2">
      <label for="check_permisssion_read2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_write2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="2">
      <label for="check_permisssion_write2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_delete2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="2">
      <label for="check_permisssion_delete2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_execute2" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="2">
      <label for="check_permisssion_execute2" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  acl_funcion1
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Read
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_read3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="r" data-id="3">
      <label for="check_permisssion_read3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Write
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_write3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="w" data-id="3">
      <label for="check_permisssion_write3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Delete
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_delete3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="d" data-id="3">
      <label for="check_permisssion_delete3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Execute
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
      <input id="check_permisssion_execute3" class="acl_permission" type="checkbox" name="acl_permission[]" value="e" data-id="3">
      <label for="check_permisssion_execute3" class="label-success"></label>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: This doesn't produce expected results

Comment: See the console.log .Its working good .Can you explain why? @charlietfl

Comment: Look at what is expected and compare yourself. Can see they are not the same

Comment: No it does not. Expected is to combine permissions for each data_id

Comment: Well, this works but i would like to combine permissions for each data_id as @charlietfl said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do something like this

```js
function showResult() {

let result = {};

$("div[id^='group-']").each((index, group) => {
  $(group).find("input").each((index, permission) => {
    if (!result[group.id]) {
      result[group.id] = {};
    }
    result[group.id][permission.id] = permission.checked;
  });
})

console.log(result);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group-g1">
<input type="checkbox" id="r" /> read
<input type="checkbox" id="w" /> write
</div>

<div id="group-g2">
<input type="checkbox" id="r" /> read
<input type="checkbox" id="w" /> write
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="showResult()" value="Click Me">
```